# form libcurl in c

Tags: html, forms, passwords, libcurl

Ive only touched libcurl a little before, but now i have to get to a page and login. This means i have to fill in a form with user name, password

Ive been searching for an example for days now, but nothing works, no explanations makes me understand what i am supposed to do.

In this example they send a form, but then what? How do I reach the information returned?
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/http-post.html

On the following link I found somebody that had a similar problem. No idea if he solved his problems. I stole the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION-line but i could not reached the updated page. (I assume I would get the information I get if I do it in a browser, but nope). On this page they also started talking about curl handling cookies. I thought cookies were used to remember usernames to simplify login.
[How do I use libcurl to login to a secure website and get at the html behind the login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550016/how-do-i-use-libcurl-to-login-to-a-secure-website-and-get-at-the-html-behind-the)

The most simple attempt I could think of was to just go to this page and submit vehicle=Car on the page below. When i do it in a browser the page returns "Input was received as:
 vehicle=Car", but I do not get it in my c/c++-program using curl.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_checkbox

Below is a part of the code I am using:

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
curl = curl_easy_init();


if(curl) {
    printf("Open %s\n", name.c_str());

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_checkbox");
    curl_easy_perform(curl);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "vehicle=Car");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, name.c_str());
    curl_easy_perform(curl);

    int i = 0;
    do{
        if (i)
        {
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, name.c_str());
        }
        printf("Try number %d \n", ++i);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &localStore);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    } while(res);

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

Comment: Where's the code for localStore( )? What do you expect from the first two calls to  curl_easy_perform(curl)?

Comment: Where's the call to curl_easy_setopt( ) that sets up CURLOPT_WRITEDATA? What are you seeing when you come into the callback function? Finally, what do you mean by "the normal callback function?" There's only one of them.

Comment: From the first call to curl_easy_perform i dont know what i expected. Its just something from one of my 100 attempts to make it work. The second time i call the function I expect that the form is posted which it is not.

Comment: I have not setup CURLOPT_WRITEDATA. It has been working fine for me without it before. Do you really need to see the callback function that i wrote? The only thing it does is to save the incoming html-code in a global pointer.

the normal callback function: was just referring to the callback function a bit odd.

Comment: Maybe i did not explain very good. When i download the page http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_checkbox with my curl-program I get the html that you see if you go to the page in your browser. Everything is great. But if I in my browser click "I have a car" and click submit, then the page changes and you can see the text: "Input was received as: vehicle=Car blablabla" and the form disappears. This does not occur in curl-program when I try to post the form. Somehow I should post the form and get new html-code returned from the server as a response to my post. But how?

Comment: Try it with GET, the way w3schools has done; put a breakpoint in the callback and see what's returned. Yes, sure, show the callback function; why not? It's only a few lines.

Comment: But first, clean up the main-program code so that it does only the call to perform that you're interested in. I have no idea what the state of libcurl is when you do those other two performs.

Comment: In fact, post the whole program. It should only be 50 or 60 lines. Then we'll both know what we're talking about. Thing is, libcurl operation is super-straightforward so you should not be having these problems. So there's something going on in your code that we need to find and fix.

Comment: I posted a code-reply somewhere here. I really dont know how to try something with a GET. What is GET?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up a callback function:

```
...
curl_res = curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, ptr );
curl_res = curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, callback );
...
```

When you come into `callback( )`, the incoming data is available on `ptr`.

Don't forget to return `realsize` on exit from `callback( )`.